# issues while incrementing and cycling through an array in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination, gallery

I built a javascript gallery (no libraries) for presentation slides as images. prev/next buttons should cycle through the array regardless of its size.
Desired bevavior
Next button: 1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2...
Prev button: 5,4,3,2,1,0,5,4...

Issues

1. change in count doesn't always change the image
2. "previous" button decrementing goes up first, and displays a -1
3. I have to call the "next" button function onload, otherwise two clicks are needed to start the images changing. I'd prefer to preload the gallery with image 0 via html or an inital function.

Please take a look https://codepen.io/cnote/pen/gOKdpxr
Thank you

I tried starting with images[0] loaded, but that requires 2 initial clicks for the buttons to work.
I've tried reworking the logic in the functions, but I'm bad at this.

```
var currentImage = 0;
var images = [];

images[0] = "https://chrismichaelides.com/img/test0.jpg";
images[1] = "https://chrismichaelides.com/img/test1.jpg";
images[2] = "https://chrismichaelides.com/img/test2.jpg";
images[3] = "https://chrismichaelides.com/img/test3.jpg";
images[4] = "https://chrismichaelides.com/img/test4.jpg";

function nextImage() {
  document.getElementById("deckImage").src = images[currentImage++];
  document.getElementById("deckNumber").innerHTML = currentImage + " of " + images.length;
  console.log("slide = " + currentImage);

  //start over
  if (currentImage >= images.length) {
    currentImage = 0;
    console.log("slide = " + currentImage);
  }
}

function prevImage() {
  document.getElementById("deckImage").src = images[currentImage--];
  document.getElementById("deckNumber").innerHTML = currentImage + " of " + images.length;
  console.log("slide = " + currentImage);

  //cycle backwards to last from first
  if (currentImage < 0) {
    currentImage = images.length - 1;
    console.log("slide = " + currentImage);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to help you.

To be honest I don't know what was the problem in code but I have a solution which I think will suit you.

I have changed functions to following:

```
function nextImage() {
  currentImage = (currentImage + 1 + images.length) % images.length;
  document.getElementById("deckImage").src = images[currentImage];
  document.getElementById("deckNumber").innerHTML =
    (currentImage + 1) + " of " + images.length;
  console.log("slide = " + currentImage);
}

function prevImage() {
  currentImage = (currentImage - 1 + images.length) % images.length;
  
  document.getElementById("deckImage").src = images[currentImage];
  document.getElementById("deckNumber").innerHTML =
    (currentImage + 1) + " of " + images.length;
  console.log("slide = " + currentImage);
}
```

Which can even be writen as:

```
function nextImage() {
  cycle(1);
}

function prevImage() {
  cycle(-1);
}

function cycle(direction) {
    currentImage = (currentImage + direction + images.length) % images.length;
  
  document.getElementById("deckImage").src = images[currentImage];
  document.getElementById("deckNumber").innerHTML =
    (currentImage + 1) + " of " + images.length;
  console.log("slide = " + currentImage);
}
```

I hope this solution is acceptable by You.

If you have additional questions or this solution is not suitable for you, describe your case so I can suggest a better one.

Best regards

PS: I am new here - if I made something wrong please point me that out

Comment: Thank you! I am also new here. I'll try this out.

Comment: update: This is excellent, thanks again. I will learn more about modulus & cycle functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code quite a lot but I have tried to keep your logic as much as possible. Instead of using an array of images and then array.length, I have hardcoded 3 into the code which represents 4 images (0, 1, 2 and 3).

```js
// You have 4 images: 0, 1, 2 and 3

var currentImage = 0;

function nextImage() {
  currentImage++;
  //start over
  if (currentImage >= 4) {
    currentImage = 0;
  }
  console.log("slide = " + currentImage);
}

function prevImage() {
  currentImage--;
  //cycle backwards to last from first
  if (currentImage < 0) {
    currentImage = 3;
  }
  console.log("slide = " + currentImage);
}

const prev = document.querySelector('#prev');
const next = document.querySelector('#next');

console.log("slide = " + currentImage);

prev.addEventListener('click', function(){
  prevImage();
});

next.addEventListener('click', function(){
  nextImage();
});
```

```html
<button id='prev'>Prev</button>
<button id='next'>Next</button>
```